# Calculating offset voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc-offset

This is a circuit that is in my textbook, the derivation for the offset voltage is not provided only the end result is. I would really appreciate it if someone could please help explain how this is the output voltage.

Feel free to edit the tags if I have made a mistake, thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

An opamp’s datasheet will include specifications for that opamp's inherent input offset voltage, Vos, and input offset current, Ios.

The output offset voltage of your circuit due to only Vos and Ios is what your textbook provided.

Vos and Ios are independent parameters so we look at their effect on the output one at a time.

Looking at Vos first, we set all other independent inputs (Ios, Vi) to zero.

Vos is modeled as a voltage on its non-inverting input. Since voltages at opamp inputs are equal in this configuration, voltage at inverting input is Vos as well, resulting in a current through R of Vos/R. That same current flows through Rf (since none flows into opamp) resulting in Vos/R * Rf voltage across it. Add those two voltages together and you have the output offset voltage component due to Vos.

[image]

For Ios, we set the other inputs (Vos, Vi) to zero.

Ios is modeled as a current coming out (or in) to opamp pins. The current on the non-inverting pin just goes into ground so has no effect. The current from the inverting input flows completely through Rf, resulting in a voltage across it of Ios * Rf, and that’s the output offset voltage component due to Ios. Why doesn’t any of Ios flow through R1? Because the voltage at the inverting input is zero, so there’s no voltage across R1 hence no current through it.
[image]

Comment: Ahhh ok that makes sense, so the capacitor acts as an open circuit in the problem?

Comment: Thanks @td127 I would really appreciate it if you were to also provide insight on my other comment.

Comment: Yes, the bias current and voltage are DC entities, so the capacitor has no effect. No DC current flows through it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how Vos is modeled which it sounds like the textbook didn't say yet or you missed.

The input offset voltage is modeled as a voltage source connecting to the non-inverting input and the value of Vos is a physical measurement you take from the opamp datasheet.

[image]

See: https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-037.pdf

The calculation is done by inserting a voltage source containing the input offset voltage at the noninverting terminal and turning off the input signal source (setting Vin to 0V by shorting to ground, or your signal reference).

Then you just use circuit analysis to calculate Vo.

Input offset currents and input bias currents have a similar approach and it looks like your equation for voltage offset includes input offset currents as well though it. Things like noise are done in a similar manner too.

[image]
See: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa059/sloa059.pdf